# Argument of sizeof()

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sizeof

The output of size of for

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int k;
    struct node *next;
};
int main()
{
    int arr[3];
    cout<<sizeof(struct node)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(struct node *)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(arr[0])<<endl;
    cout<sizeof(int *)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

is

```
8
4
12
4
4
```

I understand that struct node * is a pointer so its output should be 4. So similarly `arr` is also a pointer, so its output should also be 4 but why is it showing the size of arr array as 12?

Comment: `arr` is not a pointer, but an array. The size of an array is the number of elements times the size of one element.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Comment: Read up on [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: @Nitish May I ask why you think that `arr` is a pointer?

Answer (score 4):

> So similarly `arr` is also a pointer, so its output should also be 4 but why is it showing the size of arr array as 12?

When array name is an operand of the `sizeof` or the unary `&` then it doesn't convert to pointer to its first element. Conversion rule is not applied in these cases.
In case of

```
cout<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;
```

The `sizeof`  returns the size of the type of `arr`, which is of type `int[3]` (*array of `3` `int`s*).

**C11: 6.5.3.4:**

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand**.

Answer (score 4):

> So similarly `arr` is also a pointer

No, `arr` is not a pointer, it is an array. Although it can be freely converted to a pointer, it is a different kind of object. The results of `sizeof` indicate the amount of memory necessary to store the array of the specified size, i.e. three times the size of an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the type of `arr` is `int[3]`, not `int*` as you've assumed. So `sizeof` returns the size of the entire array.